# Toggle button for boolean input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have a simple form and want to set the value of a boolean attribute of an object to true or false. I want to toggle between two buttons. If i click button A:

```
 1. the boolean attribute gets value true
 2. button A hides and button B shows.
```

If I now click button b :

```
 1. the boolean attribute gets value false
 2. button B hides and button A shows.
```

how can I do this?

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't just use a checkbox?

Comment: hmm good point..i was overcomplicating. instead, how would i style checkboxes and replace them with toggle buttons?

Answer (score 1):

You could easily use a library like font-awesome to toggle some intuitive icons:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="control" /><label for="control">Toggle</label>

input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f00d";
    color: red;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
    content: "\f00c";
    color:green;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5o57rc30/. If you had something else in mind let me know.